# can not decode object

Tags: iphone

i am getting the error while running the application.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (MKMapView)'

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `MapKit.framework` in the project and then `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>`

You wouldn't get this error during compilation as the `NIB`s are just archives. They aren't compiled and are only unpackaged in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a MKMapView from inside a xib you will also need to include the mapkit framework in your project.